# How to manage APN tokens for users with multiple devices?

Tags: android, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a general question about managing APN tokens for when users have multiple devices. From my understanding, APN tokens change upon app reinstallation, restoring a device from a backup, and reinstalling the phone's OS. (Disclaimer that I'm new to mobile development)

In this example situation, a user uses both an iPhone and iPad and would like to receive push notifications from an app on both. The app requires users to make an account. The device tokens associated with their account would be stored in a database. I have a question on the following situation: If the user reinstalls the app on their iPhone and the new APN token is added to the database.

- If I limit the number of tokens stored for a user, how would I know which token to replace? I'm not sure if it's possible to detect the device a token comes from. If I simply replace either token, I risk the chance of overwriting the token for the iPad.
- Is it recommended practice to limit the number of tokens stored for a user? I feel that it has the potential to take up a lot of space if there's a large number of users and each user has many devices
- What are the recommended way(s) for token management for this situation? Asking in case my approach isn't a good idea

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you call Apple push server API, it may response status code `410` which indicate device is not reachable (uninstall?). You can safely remove token for `410` response.

```
410 The device token is no longer active for the topic.
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/handling_notification_responses_from_apns

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a backend service that receives APNs device tokens from your client app.
2. When you send the token to this service, you can include something to identify the user, such as a username, along with something to indicate what type of device or the operating system version they are using.
3. Then, in storage, you can store these together by user, where a user could have multiple token-device combinations tied to that single user.
4. Then when attempting to send push notifications for a user, you can check the status code of the response, and if it is a 410 response, you can safely delete the token as it will never be valid again.

Doing it this way would likely mean there would be no need to limit the number of tokens per user, because how many active devices with your app can one user really have?

Refer to the [APNs status code reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/handling_notification_responses_from_apns) for the other statuses, but 410 is the main one you'd need to handle.